Dependency not satisfieble libc6=>2.17
I want to install team viewer for Linux and I got this error:

What to do?

You've not provided any Ubuntu product or release details; so we currently can't help anyway. deb packages are built for specific releases; so we can't yet know what is, or isn't available for your unstated release.

Are you using a supported release of Ubuntu?   You'd have to be using a release that is years past EOL to not have that version available; OR a problem with your sources.  Either way without specifics as to what you're running, and other info (release being first detail required) it looks like your release is EOL or End of Life if you're using Ubuntu.

eh "libc6=>2.17"  means raring (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/raring/amd64/libc6/2.17-0ubuntu4) or newer. raring is 13.04... so you are not using a modern amd64 OS. could it be ARM?
